# maven system variable and operating system dependency

Tags: java, maven, operating-system, junit5

I have file pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.5.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>                            <application.properties>/application.properties</application.properties>
                        <web.a>${settings.localRepository}</web.a>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I use two operating system and different IDEA:
First instanse:

```
Ubuntu 18.04
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
javac 1.8.0_232
IntellijIDEA community edition 2019.3.3
```

Second instanse:

```
VirtualBox Windows 7
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
javac 1.8.0_231
Eclipse IDEA for Enterprise Java Developers 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
```

File pom.xml have system property variables:

```
<web.a>${settings.localRepository}</web.a>
```

I use code in the project:

```
@Test
    public void properties()
    {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        for(Map.Entry prop :props.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(prop.getKey()+" "+prop.getValue());
        }
    }
```

when I deploy and run build in first instance, the variable is loaded in jvm, but in the same build in second instance the loading does not occur.

who can tell: what is the reason?

Comment: first instance  Apache Maven 3.6.0
second instance Apache Maven 3.6.3

Comment: Are you executing your tests from IDE or from command line? Try not to use dot (.) in your values.

Comment: I do execute tests from IDE.

Comment: Try to run from command line and use underscore instead of dot in property values.

Comment: I performed  test in command line ubuntu:
```
mvn -X surefire:test -Dtest=BaseTest#properties test
```
And I geted result:
```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-cli) on project rti_mnp: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-cli) on project rti_mnp: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
```

Comment: But I interested performed test in idea

Comment: Can you try `mvn clean install`

Comment: result: 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project rti_mnp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/dmitriy/IdeaProjects/juglans/rti_mnp/src/test/java/BaseForTest/BaseTest.java:[3,26] package javafx.scene.shape does not exist

Comment: I haven’t settings up a project separately from the development environment, because my current tasks did not require it so far

Comment: You need to fix your imports first.

Comment: I will notify you of the correction

Comment: @fg78nc 
I install Intelij IDEA to VirtualBox Win7 and load this pom and code.


I have no problem running code in Virtualbox Win7 Intellij IDEA
but Virtualbox Win7 Eclipse stayed.

It seems to me that the matter is far from dependencies.

Comment: The first thing you need to decide. Would you like to run your unit tests with JUnit Jupiter or with JUnit 4? Furthermore remove the whole dependencies from the plugin configuration only add the dependencies you need to your project either JUnit 4 or JUnit Jupiter ...

Comment: If you resolved your imports, what is the result of `clean install`?

Comment: I solved my pom.xml and as a result I ran the command "mvn clean install". She was  worked correctly. I saw all system variable in command line, but I`m not see this result to Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @fg78nc 
somehow how